# Sensitive Data in Command Line Interfaces

Tags: security, unix, command-line, design-principles

I know it's frowned upon to use passwords in command line interfaces like in this example:

`./commandforsomething -u username -p plaintextpassword`

My understanding that the reason for that (in unix systems at least) is because it'll be able to be read in the scrollback as well as the .bash_history file (or whatever flavor shell you use).

HOWEVER, I was wondering if it was safe to use that sort of interface with sensitive data programatically while programming things. For example, in perl, you can execute a command using two ``, the exec command, or system command (I'm not 100% sure on the differences between these apart from the return value from the two backticks being the output of the executed command versus the return value... but that's a question for another post I guess).

So, my question is this: Is it safe to do things LIKE

`system("command", "userarg", "passwordarg");`

as it essentially does the same thing, just without getting posted in scrollback or history? (note that I only use perl as an example - I don't care about the answer specific to perl but instead the generally accepted principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not only about shell history.

`ps` shows all arguments passed to the program. The reason why passing arguments like this is bad is that you could potentially see other users' passwords by just looping around and executing `ps`. The cited code won't change much, as it essentially does the same.

You can try to pass some secrets via environment, since if the user doesn't have an access to the given process, the environment won't be shown. This is better, but is a pretty bad solution too (e.g.: in case program fails and dumps a core, all passwords will get written to disk).

If you use environment variables, use `ps -E` which will show you environment variables of the process. Use it as a different users than the one executing the program. Basically simulate the "attacker" and see if you can snoop the password. On a properly configured system you shouldn't be able to do it.